# querySelector para obtener precio de juego en web de Nintendo siempre sale Null

Tags: javascript, html, selectores

Intento conseguir el precio a través de querySelector:

`const price = doc.querySelector("p[data-price-box-price='current'] span")`

pero me devuelve siempre `null`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

link: https://www.nintendo.es/Juegos/Programas-descargables-Nintendo-Switch/Hollow-Knight-1125772.html

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer referencia al `document`, no a `doc`. Intenta con esto:

```
document.querySelector("p[data-price-box-price='current'] span").innerText
```

Comment: En mi caso doc es ->       const doc = htmlToElement(html) por lo que es igual a document ya que lo recojo en un método: function htmlToElement (html) {
  const template = document.createElement('template')
  html = html.trim() // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
  template.innerHTML = html
  return template.content
}
Eso no me  sirve, lo siento

Comment: En ese caso deberias editar la pregunta ya que la respuesta efectivamente retorna el valor, pero quisas no como tu esperabas. Seria de ayuda si eres un poco mas especifico en lo que necesitas